# How to Show Calendar Repeat Screen in IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have followed below url and able to navigate new event screen but need to show Repeat > Custom option
Screen .

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/Calendars/

///

```
    /// Launchs the create new event controller.

    /// </summary>

    protected void LaunchCreateNewEvent ()

    {

        // create a new EKEventEditViewController. This controller is built in an allows

        // the user to create a new, or edit an existing event.

        EventKitUI.EKEventEditViewController eventController =

            new EventKitUI.EKEventEditViewController ();



        // set the controller's event store - it needs to know where/how to save the event

        eventController.EventStore = App.Current.EventStore;



        // wire up a delegate to handle events from the controller

        eventControllerDelegate = new CreateEventEditViewDelegate (eventController);

        eventController.EditViewDelegate = eventControllerDelegate;



        // show the event controller

        PresentViewController (eventController, true, null);

    }
```

Could you please let me know , How to invoke Repeat click event in the New Event Screen .

I want to show following screen while user click on button

[image: Ref Image for Sample Screen]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Link to android component. Screenshot is IOS. Also what have you tried? Please update the question (not comment)

Comment: Question updated